# How to determine when a user has copied text

Tags: ios, copy, uimenucontroller

I am having a hard time how to figure out when a user has selected & copied text the default iOS way:

[image]

`canPerformSelector` works before presenting this menu, but I am interested in knowing after the user has pressed the copy button.

Thank You

Comment: Check the link for UIMenuController it might help you :-http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSNotification` as observer for `UIPasteboardChangedNotification:` then every time user copies it will call a method which you specified in `Notification` observer

Something like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ClipBoardChanged) name:UIPasteboardChangedNotification object:nil];

-(void)ClipBoardChanged{
   NSLog(@"ClipBoard data changed %@",[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string);
 }
```

Comment: Yea, I could somehow achieve what I wanted with this solution, so +1'd. But still looking for an answer through where I can know copied text is exactly from which UITextView in the same view. Thanks though.